# Question on toggling a button on mat table

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I change the button on the row I clicked on only?

On my ts file:
arrow = 'fa fa-caret-right fa-lg';

```
toggleArrow() {
  if (this.arrow === 'fa fa-caret-right fa-lg') {
    this.arrow = 'fa fa-sort-desc fa-lg';
  } else {
  this.arrow = 'fa fa-caret-right fa-lg';
  }
}
```

On my html file, that's how I define my action column:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
<!--edit button-->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
<span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
<!-- arrow button-->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align"
(click)="toggleArrow()">
<span class="{{arrow}}" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
</td>
</ng-container>
```

[If I click on the right arrow, it should changes to down arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v0yK.png)

[However, every row got changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuHnk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution would be to store the id of the element that you clicked on, and then if the stored id is the same as the element shown or the corresponding icon, see here you have an example with material icon but the logic is the same for your case.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8k6cta?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
elementId: number;

toggleArrow(id: number) {
  if (id === this.elementId) {
    this.elementId = null;
  } else {
    this.elementId = id;
  }
}
```

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
   <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions</th>
   <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
     <!--edit button-->
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
        <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     </button>
     <!-- arrow button-->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align"
           (click)="toggleArrow()">
       <span  [ngClass]="{
                         'fa fa-sort-desc fa-lg': element.id === elementId,
                         'fa fa-caret-right fa-lg': element.id !== elementId}" 
            aria-hidden="true"> 
      </span>
    </button>
   </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I watch the example and also read the code you wrote, then I fixed my problem! I could not think of the way of using the id to do this. I learned something new, thanks!